# Change CSS style in JQuery callback does not work?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to do something quite easy like this:

HTML:

```
<object id="InfoPage" type="text/html"></object>
```

Javacript:

```
function setInternalPage(pageAddress)
{
    $("#InfoPage").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#InfoPage").attr("data", pageAddress);
    $("#InfoPage").load(function()
    {
        $(this).css("visibility", "block");
    });

}
```

When the function gets called, the visibility is properly set to hidden, but when the callback is called (which is according to Chrome debugger), it does not set the visibility to "block", keeping it hidden.
I only need this to work on Chrome, because the goal is to have this working as GUI in CoherentUI, a tool to render HTML5 pages in games. This tool is based on Chrome.

Can you see anything blatantly wrong here? :)
Cheers!
Alex

Comment: use : ``$(this).show();`` or ``$(this).css("display","block");``

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `visibility` attribute to `visible`.

`block` is a valid setting for the `display` CSS property, not `visibility`.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

`visibility: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned as `visibility : block`. but there is no such property,

So use

```
$(this).show(); or $(this).css("display","block") or $(this).css("visibility ","visible")
```

Comment: And that did it! Thanks! I used "visibility: block" in other places and worked, which now makes me rethink how this works :D

Comment: I dont think visibility block will work, because there is no such property.

Comment: Yeah, probably is was just how the browser was handling unknown values :)